# angularjs modal service broadcast and on issue

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, broadcast, angular-broadcast

I am using [angular-modal-service](https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service) library. My logic is : when the modal is open it runs a function from `SomeService`, and `$rootScope.$broadcast` from `SomeService` to modal controller that way I can send resource from service to my modal controller. However, it doesn't fire. Please help me to figure out what I have missed. Thank you.

**Service: **

```
angular.module('ng-laravel').service('SomeService', function($rootScope, Restangular, CacheFactory, $http) {
     this.testFunction = function() {
        console.log("from service");
        $rootScope.$broadcast('event', {success:'success'});
     };
}
```

**Controller: **

```
$scope.show = function(customer_id) {

        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            inputs: {
                customer_id: customer_id
            },
            scope: $scope,
            controller: function($scope, close) {
                $scope.customer_id = customer_id;
                $scope.close = function(result) {
                    close(result, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
                };
                $scope.$on('event', function(event, data){
                    alert('yes');
                    console.log('from modal controller');
                });
            }
        }).then(function(modal) {
        SomeService.testFunction(customer_id, tour_id);
            modal.element.modal();
            modal.close.then(function(result) {
                $scope.message = "You said " + result;
            });
        });
    };
```

After switching the function it works, but...
how could i pass data in to modal? like ui-bs-modal, they have resolve.

Comment: are you missing `return this;` in your service ?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire there is no need to return `this` from service.. `service` will return `this`(context) of function implicitly

Comment: Glad to know! @PankajParkar ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're being broadcasting event before events from modal controller are binding. So before broadcasting event make sure that event listeners are registered(meaning modal controller has been loaded). So call `SomeService.testFunction();` after `showModal` method.

```
$scope.show = function(customer_id) {
    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        inputs: {
            customer_id: customer_id
        },
        scope: $scope,
        controller: function($scope, close) {
           //code as is
           //listeners will get register from here.
        }
    })
   .then(function(modal) {
       SomeService.testFunction(); //broadcasting event
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // error contains a detailed error message.
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: You should probably **chain** from the `show.modal` promise since it has to asynchronously fetch the templateURL.

Comment: @georgeawg hey thanks for heads up mate. Appreciate your catch.. :) I missed that silly thing ;)

Comment: that's great, it works. it took me couple hours. : (

Comment: The reason why, i put it on the top of the modal open part, i don't wanna pass parameter in to the controller. seem like  i have to.

Comment: Which parameters you're talking about

Comment: Then how could i pass some parameters into the that service function, i need to pass some data from parent $scope into modal

Comment: i would like  to pass 2 variable from controller $scope

Comment: @HaoPhung will go through `angular-modal-service` API and let you know, Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I read through their document, there is no resolve data provided

Answer (score 1):

You are broadcasting the event, before the modal controller is instantiated or created, as service function is called before `ModalService.showModal`. Try changing the order. That should work fine.

Inside `$scope.show` try this order

```
$scope.show = function(){
 ModalService.showModal({
       ....
       // Listen for broadcast event
 });
 SomeService.testFunction();
}
```